# Should I use expando or cache the jQuery object?

Tags: jquery, sorting

Inspired by chapter 7 of Learning jQuery 1.3 (not found in the third edition), I've put together this sort routine:

```
var rows = $table.find('tbody > tr').get();
$.each(rows, function(index, row) {
      var $cell = $(row).children('td').eq(column);
      $(row).data('sortKey',$cell);
});
rows.sort(function(a, b) {
      if ($(a).data('sortKey') < $(b).data('sortKey'))
            return -sortDirection;
      if ($(a).data('sortKey') > $(b).data('sortKey')) 
            return  sortDirection;
      return 0;
});
```

But I don't like using `$(a)` and `$(b)` on every row.

**Q:** Is there a way I can cache `$(a)` and `$(b)`?  The author uses something he calls an *expando* instead.

> This kind of property, attached to a DOM element but not a normal DOM
>   attribute, is called an expando. This is a convenient place to store
>   the key, since we need one per table row element. Now, we can examine
>   this attribute within the comparator function, and our sort is
>   markedly faster.

Comment: This seems strange. You're referencing a jQuery object via `'sortKey'` in `.data()`, then you're doing a greater/less-than comparison between the jQuery objects?

Comment: ...and why read a jQuery 1.3 book? jQuery has changed in radical ways since the 1.3 release.

Comment: I'm looking for a good sort routine without using an existing plugin because my client has all kinds of business rules that don't fit into adding tablesorter.js and moving on.

Comment: But why do a `>` comparison between two jQuery objects? That's not what you're actually using for the comparison, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two optimisations you can do here.

The first is to use [`$.data`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data) rather than [`$.fn.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data):

```
$.data(a, 'sortKey') // quick
$(a).data('sortKey') // slow
```

This is superior because it does not need to construct a new jQuery object -- you are right to think of this as a performance issue.

The second is to cache the result of `data`, so you only need to do it once.

```
rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aKey = $.data(a, 'sortKey'),
        bKey = $.data(b, 'sortKey');
    if (aKey < bKey) return -sortDirection;
    if (aKey > bKey) return  sortDirection;
    return 0;
});
```

The third optimisation (since a lonesomeday answer is buy-two-get-one-free) is to use jQuery 1.7, which is much superior to 1.3, both in speed and in other functionality.

Comment: StackOverflow: will you marry me?

Comment: I found the original code in a jQuery 1.3 book, but I load the latest version of jQuery from Google's CDN.

Comment: Speaking of optimizations, `$(row).children('td').eq(column)` would be better written as `$(row.cells[column])`, though I don't understand why OP is doing comparisons between jQuery objects in a `.sort()`.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just store them in a local variable like this:

```
rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aKey = $(a).data('sortKey');
    var bKey = $(b).data('sortKey');
    if (aKey < bKey) return -sortDirection;
    if (aKey > bKey) return sortDirection;
    return 0;
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

The author explains that you need to store the sort key for each row *somewhere*, but you do not *have* to store it using jQuery's `.data` facilities. Instead of this, he chooses to create a new property on the DOM elements instead:

```
$.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    var $cell = $(row).children('td').eq(column);
    row.sortKey = $cell; // creates a new property!
});
```

Of course the above code assumes that there will not be an existing property named `sortKey` (overwriting it, whatever it is, might lead to all sorts of problems). That's a reasonable assumption.

Afterwards, you have to also retrieve the sort key through the same mechanism used to store it: by accessing a property on the two rows being compared:

```
rows.sort(function(a, b) {
      if (a.sortKey < b.sortKey)
            return -sortDirection;
      if (a.sortKey > b.sortKey)
            return  sortDirection;
      return 0;
});
```

Since direct property access is much faster than going through jQuery's `.data` and the code used to implements it, there are substantial speed gains to be made. The only downside is that you lose the convenience of jQuery's abstract data store (guaranteed to "just work", you don't need to bother with *how* it works) since you now have taken the responsibility of implementing the data store (here, by creating a new property on the DOM elements).

As a note, the author uses the term "expando" to describe exactly this property of all JavaScript objects: you can create new properties on them whenever you feel like it.

Comment: Just beware of memory leaks in older IE. A property on a DOM element that references a jQuery object, which references the original element and other elements is bound to leak. This: `$(row).children('td').eq(column)` actually maintains a reference to all the `td` elements originally selected, as well as the `row` originally passed to `$`. So if the `row` is removed from the DOM, the `row`'s circular reference to itself will likely prevent the it and its descendants from being GC'd in some IE versions.